# SQL query for calendar creation

Tags: sql, ms-access, calendar

I'm creating an application in Microsoft Access that will be used for resource planning.

My SQL table is roughly structured as follows:

```
ID    DATE    SHIFT    PERSON
```

What I'm struggling with is retrieving the data from the table in a way I can use to populate a planning form.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
NAME     16/11    17/11    18/11    19/11    20/11    21/11    22/11
Person 1 Day      Day      Day      Day      Day
Person 2 Night    Night    Night    Night    Night
Person 3 Day      Day               Day      Day      Day
```

However, I'm not getting anywhere near to finding an SQL query that will get me this result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your columns aren't fixed, that makes it complicated. If you would have a query for each user or for each day used in the report it is easy.

Comment: Have you considered crosstabs?

Answer (score -1):

Enter all your data into MS Access.  Use crosstab query wizard as follows:

```
    1) Select Your table <next>
    2) For Row headings select "Person"  <next>
    3) For Column headings choose "Shift_Date" (since date is a reserved                            
       word used column name of Shift_date) <next>
    4) By which interval? select "Date" <next>
    5) For: What number do you want calculated for each column and row
       intersection?  choose "Shift", and for function choose "Max"
    6) Finish
```

Comment: It gives me a very simple SQL query I can use as a basis for what I need exactly.

Comment: Great!  You can launch from a form and supply a field with Week ending date, to filter to a specific week.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to upvote my answer since it solved your problem?